# Laravel PostTooLargeException

Tags: laravel, php-ini

No matter how many times I change my php.ini and validate for video uploads I keep getting an error from Laravel saying PostTooLargeException.

This is in my controller:

```
'video' => 'required|mimes:mp4,flv,wmv,avi,mov,qt|max:100000',
'city'  =>'required',
```

Here is the form:

```
{!!Form::open(array('route'=>'profile.store','class'=>'formform','files'=>'true','method'=>'POST','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) !!}

{{Form::text('city','',array('placeholder'=>'City and State','class'=>'form-control', 'size'=>'35px','height'=>'15px','id'=>'location-input','autocomplete'=>'off'))}}
{{Form::file('video',array('id'=>'file','class'=>'thefile'))}}


{{Form::submit('Submit', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger form-control','id'=>'submitty','style'=>'  background:#F88B22;'))}}
{!!Form::close() !!}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::resource('profile','ProfileController',['except'=>'edit']);
Route::get('editlisting/{companyname}','ProfileController@edit');
```

Comment: I don't think the max validation rule is in megabytes.

Comment: here us your solution http://tjd-studio.com/blog/article/posttoolargeexception-error-in-laravel-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: Debug `ValidatePostSize::handle()`: What's the value of `$max`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I think I got it now. But i am having an issue. laravel is supposed to validate the file 'video' => 'required|mimes:mp4,flv,wmv,avi,mov,qt|max:100000', but its not doing it i just keep getting  PostTooLargeException. I know the file is big but i validated it. Whats happening here?

Comment: How big is the file?

Comment: the file size is 500mb

Comment: What behavior do you expect? That the validation gets executed but fails?

Comment: oh wow! I promise you it didn't fail on me before. I have to submit this website on the web. I don't want when people uploading videos they see that error message i need a way to tell them that the file is too large. How can I do that?

Comment: When uploading a file PHP first checks `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize`. Then `ValidatePostSize` gets executed. Then your custom validation. So if you want your validation to get reached, the size limits in `php.ini` have to be large enough.

Comment: Oh really wow that makes so much sense now! Ok I think I know what to do now. I will let you know if I have any issues. But thanks so much!!

Comment: Hey everything is good now I just really want to thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

value of `upload_max_filesize` must not be greater than `post_max_size` in `php.ini` file

Comment: I will make sure of that. I have a question. When I upload the execution time is very slow is there a way I could speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do like this,

Make sure u have `enctype=multipart/form-data` in your form

```
 'video' => 'file|mimes:mp4,flv,wmv,avi,mov,qt|max:10240',
```

You have to use the `file` while you are validating its size.

Hope this helps

Comment: i did that it still does the same thing

Comment: can I compress the files. If so how can I do that?

Comment: i just edited everything I added my form controller and form code take a look

Comment: @Stephany.S123 post your routes too

Comment: lerval  I just did it

Comment: @Stephany.S123  try this`{!!Form::open(array('route'=>'profile.store','class'=>'formform','files'=>true,'method'=>'POST','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) !!}
`

Comment: @Stephany.S123 actually you have `true` as a string try that

Comment: it don't work. I really need to compress the videos how do I go about that. I heard they say use ffmpeg i don't know what to do